# Sum positive and negative values vba userform

Tags: vba, function, textbox, userform

I'm fairly new to VBA and i'm trying to sum multiple textboxes in VBA userforms. However, when i try to enter a positive value in the textbox, I'm faced with a debug error. initially the textbox was stopping me from inputting negative numbers.

Can someone please give me a hand?

Thanks

```
Private Sub TxtRetirementAW()

    Dim Total As Currency
    Total = 0

If Len(TextBox213.Value) <> 0 Then Total = Total + (TextBox213.Value)
If Len(TextBox214.Value) <> 0 Then Total = Total + (TextBox214.Value)
If Len(TextBox215.Value) <> 0 Then Total = Total + (TextBox215.Value)
If Len(TextBox216.Value) <> 0 Then Total = Total + (TextBox216.Value)
If Len(TextBox217.Value) <> 0 Then Total = Total + (TextBox217.Value)
If Len(TextBox218.Value) <> 0 Then Total = Total + (TextBox218.Value)
If Len(TextBox219.Value) <> 0 Then Total = Total + (TextBox219.Value)
If Len(TextBox220.Value) <> 0 Then Total = Total + (TextBox220.Value)

TxtTotalAWRetirement.Value = Format(Total, "£#,##0.00")

End Sub
```

```
Private Function Numeric0nly(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger) As MSForms.ReturnInteger

        Dim Key As MSForms.ReturnInteger

        Select Case KeyAscii

        Case 46, 48 To 57 ' accept only decimal "." and numbers [0-9]
            Set Key = KeyAscii
        Case Else
        KeyAscii = 0 'Minor Bug Earlier
            Set Key = KeyAscii
            End Select
            Set Numeric0nly = Key

End Function
```

```
Private Sub Textbox213_Change()
TxtRetirementAW
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Textbox213_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
KeyAscii = Numeric0nly(KeyAscii)

End Sub
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "a debug error".

Comment: Your NumericOnly method does not allow entry of a "-" character.